# Azure DevOps Web view for Pull Requests for a given Release

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a web view in Azure DevOps that shows a nice summary of all the Pull Requests for a given release?

I.e. between the "Current" release and the last one.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not exist in Azure DevOps.

You can install some ADO extensions that can help you achieve it (not exactly what you want, but close...):

- [Pull Request Dashboard](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanstedman.tfs-pullrequest-dashboard) - In the settings you can filter PR's by date (so filter by the current release date).
- [Pull Request Search](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.pull-request-search) - You can search PR's by date.